# Is it possible to make a search tool in batch?

Tags: batch-file, cmd

what i am trying to achieve is a search feature that will allow the user to put in the name of a file and it will find that file and save the file's path as a variable so I'm able to use the file path later on is this possible i have not been able to find any information on this

Comment: so, a user comes on your website, adds a url, and later you will use that path to find info on that page; is this what you need ?

Comment: no its for my batch file that moves files around im trying to make it find a folder to move from X to Z

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write a batch file like:

```
@echo OFF

for /f %%F in ('dir %2\%1 /s /b') do 
    (
        <nul (set /p msg=%%~nxF )
        for /f %%G in ('dir %3\%%~nxF /s /b') do 
            (
                if exist %%G 
                    (
                        @echo found at %%G
                    ) 
            )
     )
```

Now here:

`%1` is the user provided file name

`%2` is the user provided directory to search first.

`%3` is the user provided directory to search second.

To save the details into a text file use:

```
FindAll MyFile.txt d:\dir1 d:\dir2 > MyFile_report.txt 2>&1
```

The `<nul (set /p)` trick will output text to the console without a new line

Comment: it seems that its possible; you've got your answer;